# Variable from jquery to PHP wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm building in Wordpress, I know I need to use AJAX, but not how to do so.

I have a drop down select box, when the user selects an option a div appears.

The data in that div needs to be pulled from a custom post, so I have a php variable to do this.

What I need to do, is be able to change that php variable based on the selection of the drop down.

I can do this in jQuery, but I don't know how to transfer the jQuery var to php.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').change(function(){
    $( 'select option:selected').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('value')=='choose'){
            hide_visible();
        }  

        var val = $('#course_select option:selected').val();

        var course_id;  

        if (val == 'CPR'){
            course_id = 106; <!--  I need to send this to php -->
            $( '#course_id' ).val(course_id); 
        };


        if($(this).attr('value') == val){
            if ($( '.course-info ' ).is(':visible')) {
                $( '.course-info' ).slideUp( 'slow' ).delay(700);
                $( '.iframe' ).slideUp( 'slow' );
                $( '.form' ).slideUp( 'slow' );
                $( '.'+ val ).slideDown( 'slow' );
            }else{
                $('.iframe').slideUp( 'slow' );
                $( '.course-info' ).slideUp( 'slow' );
                $( '.'+ val  ).slideDown( 'slow' );
            };
        }           
    });
}).change();
```

});

Comment: Can we see some code examples? It's quite hard to understand exactly what you're trying to achieve here...

Comment: why not just request the content from the server based on the dropdown?

Comment: If there are a limited number menu selection, why not just pre-populate all the div's and use javascript/jQuery to show the one related to the current selection?  This a more straight-forward approach if you don't want to mess with AJAX and perhaps having to build a backend script to work with it.

Comment: @Scopey Here is the idea, working except the content.
If you select Anaphylaxis from the drop down it shows how it will appear with the content.

http://lindykulpa.com/ph/first-aid-training/

Comment: @MikeBrant I had thought about this, but there is quite a few options and the template will be applied to a couple of different sections..

Comment: Look into $.load jquery function (http://api.jquery.com/load/). When a user selects from the drop down, you can use $.load to load the information required from the server.

From a performance point of view though, provided the information isn't too expansive you might as well just provide all the information on page load and then hide and show the information on request with jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your edited question, you can just do something like the following:

```
$('.result-element').load('my-page.php?courseid=' + courseId);
```

Look into api.jquery.com/load for more information is using jQuery.load().

Your my-page.php can get "courseid" from $_GET['courseid'] and you can just echo your raw HTML as a "partial" which jQuery will automatically add to the '.result-element' element.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I'm just going to going lofi for now, to get the job done, then maybe revisit my grand plan at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

You won't need your PHP variable.

On the change event of your drop down, fetch the value selected, then build your ajax query and send it to the server.

Checkout the following functions of jQuery: `ajax()`, `change()`, `val()`, `html()`, `show()`.

You also need to setup an endpoint for jQuery to request the data. Something like http://domain.com/api/get-my-data. That's a wordpress task (ie. PHP). This endpoint / script should return a JSON encoded object that contains the content of your div.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps additional that you're using jquery also. cheers men :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').change(function(){
$( 'select option:selected').each(function()
{
    if($(this).attr('value')=='choose')
    {
        hide_visible();
    }  

    var val = $('#course_select option:selected').val();

    var course_id;  

    if (val == 'CPR')
     {
        course_id = 106; // Sample code where you can send your jquery variable to php page
        $.post("send_variable.php", {id:val}, function(data){
                alert(data) //shouts the data from send_variable.php page    
                $("#hiddenTextbox").val(data); //this passes the value from send_variable.php to a textbox with Id(hiddenTextbox) into the page 
        });
        $( '#course_id' ).val(course_id); 
     }


    if($(this).attr('value') == val)
    {
        if ($( '.course-info ' ).is(':visible')) 
        {
            $( '.course-info' ).slideUp( 'slow' ).delay(700);
            $( '.iframe' ).slideUp( 'slow' );
            $( '.form' ).slideUp( 'slow' );
            $( '.'+ val ).slideDown( 'slow' );
        }
        else
        {
            $('.iframe').slideUp( 'slow' );
            $( '.course-info' ).slideUp( 'slow' );
            $( '.'+ val  ).slideDown( 'slow' );
        }
    } 
 }

});
}).change();
```

Here's the code for send_variable.php

```
 <?php
     $val1 = $_POST['id'];
     echo $val1; //thus returning the data that depends on your selected from dropdown
  ?>
```

Hopes this helps :)

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for your reply.

As this is in wordpress, where do I put send_variable.php? And how do I get the var back into my page to use?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar in making any wordpress. Is there any way where you can add another page there? If so then you can just copy the codes in send_variable.php. You can get the var back by simply making a hidden textbox. See updated code above.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates
Making a page through wordpress doesn't make any new file.... php or otherwise.
It's just info stored in your database.
To be able to run your php from within your page, you have a couple options.

You could make a new page template following the guidance I linked to above. Name it something like mynews.php and assign it to your news page. The new template could simply be an exact copy of page.php with the appropriate header, and your code from your original post inserted

Comment: If you don't want to go that route, there are plugins which allow php code to be run from directly within a post/page

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/
is one of them.....